# Perturbed Bessel equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions, perturbation-theory, stability-in-odes

Hi I am studying some physics that in a liminal case produce the Bessel equation:

$ U''_k(\tau)+\omega_k^2(\tau)U_k(\tau)=0 $

Where in the liminal case $\omega_k^2(\tau)=k^2 - \frac{C}{\tau^2}$ with $C$ being a constant.

I am studying a slight perturbed variant i.e. $\omega^2(\tau)=k^2-\frac{C+f(\tau)}{\tau^2}$ where the relative magnitude of $f(\tau)$ relative to $C$ is very very small.

Does anybody know of a stability analysis of the Bessel equation in that respect, or otherwise have some experience and can share some insight into this problem?

BTW the actual solutions for the unperturbed problem is some modified Bessel functions $U_k = \sqrt{-\tau}J_{\tilde{C}}(k\tau)$ Where $\tilde{C}$ is some constant that is related to $C$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are looking at second order ODE, possibly on the positive half line,  with a coefficient that degenerates at the origin. Because there is no source, and you still give a non zero solution, you are asking about eigenmodes. And the type of eigenmodes you are looking for are the ones which do not blow up at the origin, and looking at your solution satisfy some periodicity assumption at infinity?

Comment: Actually, the type of solutions I am interested in are exactly the ones that diverge at x->0.
Yes, I am looking for eigenmodes essentially.